# Sharepoint | Developing webparts for Public Facing Site

Tags: apps-development

I would like to develop a custom webpart for a public facing website that DOESNT appear in an IFrame, after trying all the tutorials here "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/fp179930.aspx" it appears I cant do this, the only option is creating a on-premise hosted app, but wsp files can't be enabled on "Office365 hosted websites" I need a plugin that for example can be downloaded from app store and wont appear in an iframe for the purpose of SEO etc.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Apps for SharePoint will always be displayed in iFrames when in AppPart mode

Comment: Ok thanks, am i correct in the assumption that the only work around is to develop a .wsp sharepoint solution / web parts and run this on a on-premise setup?

Comment: If you need it as WebParts, yes. But bear in mind that all Apps also can be run in "Full mode" where it does not render in an iframe

Comment: Yes i did create a solution that had a 'full' mvc site that inherited the current sites theme from the '15' folder, however the pitfall is that the web parts associated arent SEO friendly because of the iFrame which is a shame really because thats my only snag to a great app model.